# My textbox shrinks in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my DocSearchUI, part of the larger frame in `main`

```
class DocSearchUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
         Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
         self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
         self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
         self.search_button = Button(self, text="Search")
         self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
         self.search_bar = Text(self, width=1, height=1)
         self.search_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)
         self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand='yes')
```

My main has this:

```
self.search_frame = Frame(self.master, self.editor_frame)
self.search_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
self.search_UI = DocSearchUI(self.search_frame)
```

The outcome is this:
[image]

Why is my search textbox shrinks? Thanks.

Comment: `search_bar = Text(self, width=1, height=1)` shouldn't you set the width to something greater than 1?

Comment: @Joel Cornett: there's actually an advantage to creating a Text or Entry widget with a width of 1, though it's hard to describe in this tiny comment area. The short version is, under some circumstances you get better behavior when the window shrinks to be smaller than the requested size of the widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Interesting. So if you set the width to _> k_ and the window is resized to _< k_ the textbox will extend beyond the size of the window, but won't if you set it equal to 1?

Comment: @Joel Cornett: It has to do with how Tkinter will clip widgets once they are all at their requested size but the window is made smaller. A smaller requested size means the clipping happens later rather than sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's because you give a weight of 1 to column 3 of the frame, but the text widget (text? an Entry seems like a more natural choice...) is in column 1 and 2. Therefore it is in a column of weight 0, which means it won't grow.

Try giving a weight to column 1 or two. Though, if you're doing a single row of widgets and you want the text widget to fill the remainder of that row you might want to use pack -- it's a little easier to get the layout right since you don't have to count columns or apply weights.